# Need last element of an array using Javascript Splice function

Tags: javascript

I have a list of array I only need last element in array.

For example.

var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

My Required result is ["Mango"].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pop()` at the simplest level to get the last element only and assign that value as an array to the original array. Unlike `splice` you do not need to worry about calculating the length value of the array.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits = [fruits.pop()];
console.log(fruits)
```

Comment: **Notice** This returns the last element and removes it from the original array

Comment: Well, I see two possible issues with this solution: 1) your result is an array containing the last element of fruits instead of just the element and 2) by using pop() you will remove the last item from the array, which is not always desirable.

Comment: @BartHofland that what OP needs `I have a list of array I only need last element in array` which means he needs only last element to survive in array

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek that what OP needs `I have a list of array I only need last element in array` which means he needs only last element to survive in array

Comment: Correct. THe last element. Not "an array with the last element".

Comment: @BartHofland again see OP clarifies here `My Required result is ["Mango"].` `Mango` is inside an array

Comment: Ah. I see your point. His question is a bit unclear. Does he wants the last element in an array or the last element in the array...

Comment: Yes, you are correct. My apologies.

Comment: @BartHofland that is fine. I admit it is quite confusing

Comment: @all Thanks But for your response. I got my desired output by fruits.splice(0,fruits.length-1)

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal it's fine. I mentioned it in case OP would be surprised why the original array is changed or his code would behave weirdly because of that. Treat it as an extension of your answer, not as a correction. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can access it with his index and the array length

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits = [fruits[fruits.length-1]];
console.log(fruits)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access last index of array by getting array length and accessing last index.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var val = array[array.length - 1]; // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way you can get last index:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Get the last element in an Array</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

var x = new Array(2,3,4);

alert(x[x.length-1]);

//-->
</script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) with a negative value, from the end, and return an array of the last item.

Slicing does not mutate the original array.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"],
    wanted = fruits.slice(-1);

console.log(wanted);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **get the last element of an array** with the following methods:

**1st:**

```js
var fruits =  ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var fruits = fruits.slice(-1)[0];
console.log(fruits);
```

**2nd:**

```js
var fruits  = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var fruits = fruits[fruits.length-1];
console.log(fruits);
```